# Should we migrate this question to AskUbuntu?

Tags: discussion, migration

The question [How to install zeal in ubuntu 12.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656567/how-to-install-zeal-in-ubuntu-12-04) seems to fit better in [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com).

**Normally** I would either

- vote to close it as **`Off Topic > Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)`** and explain this there
- or I would flag this as 
  *"in need of moderator intervention
  "* and would explain that *"This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"* by specifying (the mentioned Ask Ubuntu)

**However** I've come here and ask first before taking any action for two reasons:

- The question is very old and maybe it is not worth doing that. Besides it has almost 2k view and for sure has helped a lot of people (Question and answers have more than 2 upvotes).
- The last time I did something like this my flag was declined (I cannot see the [flagged question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48874077/ubuntu-modify-permissions-w-o-chattr-i) though). In my opinion the flag should had not been declined (nevermind).
  [image]

**Finally**, if we analyze its content, it clearly is off topic. It has nothing to do with programming at all.

So, what should be the correct course of action in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not even moderators can migrate questions more than 60 days old. To even make this possible you'd have to make a case to an employee with database access that they should make a special exception for this question.

A question with a two upvotes and two answers probably isn't going to qualify as such an exception.

As to why your previous flag was declined, we only migrate new questions of high quality that we think are likely to be received well on the target site. The question you flagged wasn't the greatest, so I'm guessing the moderator who acted on that didn't think it deserved to be migrated.

Comment: Thanks @Brand Larson for the clarification _" we only migrate new questions of high quality that we think are likely to be received well on the target site"_. Now it makes sense to me why the previous flag was declined. And for the rest of the (useful) information.

Answer (score 5):

No.  It's too old.  There's no reason to move it anywhere.  No one using Ubuntu would ever be caught using Ubuntu 12.04 anyway.

The correct course of action in this specific case is to do nothing.  Close it if you think it's off-topic.